# Tune a LSTM model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I and building an LSTM model to predict a word given a sequence of characters. For now, my dataset has just ~3k words that are alphaNumeric. For some reason I'm hitting a max accuracy of .84 and I can't seem to get past that. I've tried adding additional LSTM layers, changed learning-rate and batch-size, but I can't get past the .84 accuracy limit.

I'm looking for guidance on how should I go about investigating this. I was planning on using Hyperas to tweak the model. I'm not sure if tweaking would help as I'm hitting that .84 limit while going from a 3 layer LSTM with 12 cells all the way to 3 layer with 24 cells.

Here is my definition of the model:

```py
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(24, input_shape=(data.getMaxLen(), data.uniqueChars), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(24, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(24, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(12)))
model.add(AveragePooling1D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(data.uniqueTokensCount, activation='softmax'))

optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.0005)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(data.X, data.Y,
                    batch_size=data.uniqueTokensCount,
                    epochs=10000,
                    callbacks=[print_callback])
```

Model: 3xLSTM (24 cells), 1x Dense (12 cells), Max Length 15
[image: Model1]
Model: 3xLSTM (24 cells), 1x Dense (12 cells), Max Length 8
[image: Model2]
Model: 3xLSTM (12 cells), 1x Dense (6 cells), Max Length 8
[image: Model3]

Comment: I would try making your LSTM `Bidirectional` with concatenation. Average Pooling may also be hindering performance. You also may want to increase the latent dimension of the LSTM

Comment: I'm gonna try Bidirectional is a bit. It sounds promising. Do you think i need to increase the cells or make the model deeper?

Comment: What are the differences between the three plots of accuracy and loss? It is interesting indeed that it seems like there is a hard ceiling for the accuracy.

Comment: @nicoring I'm gonna update the my post with that info

Comment: @nicoring, done adding the parameters used for those models

Comment: Ok interesting, it seems to me that there is some upper limit that is currently achievable in your accuracy, which is independent of the model. The smallest model already achieves the best performance, while bigger models only have higher variance. I would review how you calculate the accuracy or have a look what is the max theoretical accurracy in your specific problem.

Comment: how would i calculate the max theoretical accuracy for my dataset? The model accuracy is being calculated by keras itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see what your validation loss is. It is possible that you are overfitting and not getting past 0.84 because of this. Seeing that your training accuracy is fluctuating, you can try adding dropouts or regularizers to prevent overfitting.